# Google Sheet: How to reverse and transpose a row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, row, reverse, transpose

Need to reverse and transpose a row in google sheet

[image]

like below

[image]

Tried below formula but didn't reversed the order. Help me out!

```
=FILTER(TRANSPOSE(A1:E1),TRANSPOSE(A1:E1)<>"")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=SORT(TRANSPOSE(A1:E1),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A1:E1)),)
```

- `SEQUENCE` to create a array of sequential numbers
- `SORT` to sort them in reverse

If you need to check for blanks, use `QUERY` to filter:

```
=QUERY(SORT(TRANSPOSE(A1:E1),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A1:E1)),),"where Col1 is not null",0)
```

Comment: This helps me perfectly. Additionally, if some cells in between or at the end holds empty value how to skip those?

Comment: @user12345 added query to filter blanks

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY(SORT(FLATTEN(A1:1), FLATTEN(COLUMN(A1:1)), 0),
 "where Col1 is not null")
```

or:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(VLOOKUP(ROW(A1), {ROW(A1), A1:1}, 
 TRANSPOSE(SORT(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A1:1))+1, 1, 0)), 0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=query(sort(transpose({ARRAYFORMULA(column(A1:E1));A1:E1}),1,false),"select Col2")
```

[image]